# Given two functions, generate all nested applications of the functions to a given order

Tags: functions, function-construction, iteration, iterators, nested-function

I have two functions $f$ and $g$. Given some order parameter $n$, I want to created all nested applications of $f$ and $g$ and save them in a list. For example, for order 1 we will have `{f(x),g(x)}`. For order 2 we have `{f(f((x)),f(g(x)),g(f(x)),g(g(x))}` and so in. In general, for order $n$ the list should contain $2^n$ items.

Answer (score 7):

First level

```
a = {f[x], g[x]};
```

Second level

```
b = Flatten @ Transpose @ Query[All, {f, g}] @ a
```

> {f[f[x]], f[g[x]], g[f[x]], g[g[x]]}

Subsequent levels

```
nesting[x_, n_] := Nest[Flatten @* Query[All, {f, g}], x, n]
```

```
nesting[b, 1]
```

```
{f[f[f[x]]], g[f[f[x]]],
 f[f[g[x]]], g[f[g[x]]], 
 f[g[f[x]]], g[g[f[x]]], 
 f[g[g[x]]], g[g[g[x]]]}
```

```
list = nesting[b, 2]
```

```
{f[f[f[f[x]]]], g[f[f[f[x]]]], f[g[f[f[x]]]], g[g[f[f[x]]]], 
 f[f[f[g[x]]]], g[f[f[g[x]]]], f[g[f[g[x]]]], g[g[f[g[x]]]], 
 f[f[g[f[x]]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[g[f[x]]]], g[g[g[f[x]]]], 
 f[f[g[g[x]]]], g[f[g[g[x]]]], f[g[g[g[x]]]], g[g[g[g[x]]]]}
```

Another ordering:

```
SubsetMap[ReverseSort, SubsetMap[Sort, list, 1 ;; 8], 9 ;; 16]
```

```
{f[f[f[f[x]]]], f[f[f[g[x]]]], f[g[f[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[x]]]], 
 g[f[f[f[x]]]], g[f[f[g[x]]]], g[g[f[f[x]]]], g[g[f[g[x]]]], 
 g[g[g[g[x]]]], g[g[g[f[x]]]], g[f[g[g[x]]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], 
 f[g[g[g[x]]]], f[g[g[f[x]]]], f[f[g[g[x]]]], f[f[g[f[x]]]]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will wait a bit before deciding which answer to accept.

Answer (score 7):

**Using `Composition`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

comps[flist_List, n_ /; n > 0] := Module[
  {t = Tuples[flist, n]},
  Fold[Composition, #]@x & /@ t
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

```
comps[{f, g}, 1]
```

> {f[x], g[x]}

```
comps[{f, g}, 2]
```

> {f[f[x]], f[g[x]], g[f[x]], g[g[x]]}

```
comps[{f, g}, 4]
```

> {f[f[f[f[x]]]], f[f[f[g[x]]]], f[f[g[f[x]]]], f[f[g[g[x]]]],
> f[g[f[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[x]]]], f[g[g[f[x]]]], f[g[g[g[x]]]],
> g[f[f[f[x]]]], g[f[f[g[x]]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], g[f[g[g[x]]]],
> g[g[f[f[x]]]], g[g[f[g[x]]]], g[g[g[f[x]]]], g[g[g[g[x]]]]}

Also explore `RightComposition`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will wait a bit before deciding which answer to accept. Both seem to work fine...